# How to retrieve data from a QAbstractListModel using PyQt

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt

I have created my own custom QListModel based on QAbstractListModel. The issue is that I am not sure how to query the data in the model once I have entered it. I am assuming I need a getter function of some kind but I am not sure how to implement that.

```
class CustomListModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):

def __init__(self, list = [], parent = None):
    QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent)
    self.__list = list

def rowCount(self, parent):

    return len(self.__list)

def data(self, index, role):


    row = index.row()
    value = self.__list[row]

    if role == QtCore.Qt.ToolTipRole:
        return 'test1: ' + value[0] + ' test2: ' + value[1]

    if role == QtCore.Qt.DecorationRole:

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(images + 'small2.png')
        icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)
        return icon

    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        return 'test1: ' + value[0] + ' test2: ' + value[1]

def flags(self, index):

    return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

def setData(self, index, value, role = QtCore.Qt.EditRole):

    if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:

        row = index.row()


def insertRows(self, position, rows, newList, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):

    self.beginInsertRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1)

    for i in range(rows):
        self.__list.insert(position, newList)

    self.endInsertRows()
    return True

def removeRows(self, position, rows, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
    self.beginRemoveRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1)

    for i in range(rows):
        value = self.__list[position]
        self.__list.remove(value)

    self.endRemoveRows()
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt need a getter function I just needed to do the following.

```
data = self.list.index(0).data(role = QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole).toPyObject()
```

With self.list being an instance of the CustomListModel.

The issue that I was having was that the objects that were returning were Qt objects rather than Python objects and so I wasn't able to extract the data.